# Select from this Table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server called `tbl_spe` that contains some specifications of a computer like `CPU, RAM,...` 
I want to select all rows with this condition: all rows that their RAM are less than 1GB
We can simply write this query:

```
Select * from tbl_spe where RAM <= 1
```

Or something like that, but the problem is about table's data :

```
ID  RAM

159 2GB DDR2
160 256MB DDR
161 3GB DDR2
162 512MB DDR
```

How can I extract number's part of the RAM field? and tell to query select all row that their RAM are less than 1GB?

Comment: You can keep One more field/coloumn in this table where you will store only numbers not string as you are doing then it will be easy to do that ..

Comment: It would be better to change your design so that the *amount* of RAM is kept in one field and the *type* of RAM in another. Then finding computers with less than 1 GB RAM will be trivial. Also, try not to write queries 'select * from'; instead retrieve only the fields that you need.

Comment: I second that suggestion by Newman. Having a separate numeric field will be better in terms of select performance as you won't have to do all that string manipulation stuff. Also, you can add a `unit` field so you can do conversion. The unit field can have `MB` or `GB`, etc. Then you can have probably have a unit table and assign values for each unit and ratio so you can do conversion later.

Comment: I again agree to split up the value into separate fields. However I know that is sometimes not viable, in fact I came across a similar issue recently, hence my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,
       CONVERT(varchar(100), LEFT(RAM, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', RAM) - 1)) AS RAMValue,
       RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(100), LEFT(RAM, PATINDEX('%[ ]%', RAM) - 1)), 2) AS RAMFactor
FROM   tbl
)
SELECT *
FROM   CTE
WHERE  RAMFactor = 'MB'
```

Here is an example in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9680f/13)

If you wanted to have less than 2GB then change the WHERE clause to this:

```
WHERE  RAMFactor = 'MB'
   OR  (RAMFactor = 'GB' AND RAMValue < 2)
```

The first check will get all records that are measured in 'MB', therefore less than a 'GB'.
The second check will get all records that are measured in 'GB' and have a value of less than 2, therefore 'GB' values less than 2GB.

Comment: While this is a good looking solution, I believe this will include the `GB` value.

Comment: This was not the code I saw earlier. Yes now it does look it will work, without going to the sqlfiddle. I'll +1 so others, especially the OP, will not be misguided by my comment.

Comment: OP is asking for getting the data which RAM is less than or equal to 1 GB.....But Your query retreives the record which is less than 1 GB i.e. 256MB

Comment: @LolCoder Oh yeah, completely missed that bit! I have modified it to give a few more options for creating a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @XN16 Thanks a lot , now how can I get RAMs that are less than 1GB?

Comment: @Sirwan Afifi My example above will already give you this as all RAM values that have a 'RAMFactor' of MB will be less than 1GB. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: @XN16 Thanks but I cant find 'WHERE' clause, how can I change that to 2G RAMs?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi The WHERE clause is at the bottom, if you want to get all the records that are less than 2GB then I have given another example in my original post at the bottom for this.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_spe
WHERE CAST( SUBSTRING(RAM,0,PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',RAM)) AS INT ) <=1
```

`PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',RAM)` finds the position of first alphabet and SUBSTRING function extracts number from string.

**EDIT :** 
Below query takes into consideration RAM in MB and GB . Otherwise above query incorrectly returns 256MB Ram greater than 1GB

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_spe
 WHERE 
     ( CAST( SUBSTRING(RAM,0,PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',RAM)) AS INT ) <=1 AND
       RAM like '%GB%' )
      OR
     ( CAST( SUBSTRING(RAM,0,PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',RAM)) AS INT ) <=1000 AND
       RAM like '%MB%' )
```

Comment: There's a problem with this answer. This will not work for values with DDR.

Comment: @von v. Yep , I missed DDR example . Now corrected +1 to you sir.

Answer (score 4):

I have taken value(size) extraction part of RAM field using @XN16 query and used `CASE` condition in `WHERE` clause to apply the condition according to the size given.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_spe
WHERE 1 <=
   CASE
     WHEN CHARINDEX('MB',SUBSTRING(RAM, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', RAM) - 1)) > 0
     THEN CAST(CONVERT(varchar(100), LEFT(RAM, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', RAM) - 1)) AS FLOAT) * 0.001 
     WHEN CHARINDEX('GB',SUBSTRING(RAM, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', RAM) - 1)) > 0
     THEN CAST(CONVERT(varchar(100), LEFT(RAM, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', RAM) - 1)) AS FLOAT)
   END
```

In above `CASE` condition, you can add the case for KB and add the logic to get GB from given size of KB.....

Check out ***[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9680f/25)***

Answer (score 1):

Well I have crossed the same problem so I created my own function for this (of course I got some help from my friends in the internet) this is the function:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION ExtractInteger(@String VARCHAR(2000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Count INT
DECLARE @IntNumbers VARCHAR(1000)
SET @Count = 0
SET @IntNumbers = ''

WHILE @Count <= LEN(@String)
BEGIN
IF SUBSTRING(@String,@Count,1) >= '0'
AND SUBSTRING(@String,@Count,1) <= '9'
BEGIN
SET @IntNumbers = @IntNumbers + SUBSTRING(@String,@Count,1)
END
SET @Count = @Count + 1
END

RETURN @IntNumbers
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_spe
WHERE RAM LIKE '[1-9]GB%'
OR RAM LIKE '___MB%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1) Run a custom function to just extract the numeric values from `RAM` column.

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[RemoveNumericCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    Declare @NumRange as varchar(50) = '%[0-9]%'
    While PatIndex(@NumRange, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@NumRange, @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```

2) And second step, simply use the function

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT *,
          RemoveNumericCharacters(RAM) AS Nums
   FROM tbl_spe
)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE Nums <= 1
```